# Git show the difference between two git-diff

Tags: git, github, git-diff

**SCENARIO**

- There is a temporary branch(temp1) running independently with commits `A..B..C..D..E..`
- There is another feature branch (feature1) with other commits `P..Q..R..S..T`
- Now, developer cherry-picks the commit 'C' from temp branch and merge into feature1 (Assumption: there are no any conflicts as they are completely different area of code) to get `P..Q..R..S..T..C1`
  (Note: This C1 has same changes as C used to have, but just the different commit ids as we know commit is immutable in GIT)

NOW, As a dev, I want to verify the diff between `T..C1` and `B..C` to make sure every contents are exact same.

**How far I have been?**

1. I can see the changes made in C from temp branch as: `$git diff C C~1`
2. I can see the changes made in C1 from feature1 branch as: `$git diff C1 C1~1`
3. This shows exact files when used with --name-only attribute

   $git diff C C~1 --name-only

   $git diff C1 C1~1 --name-only

**QUESTION:**
I want to see the diff between (1) and (2) to verify the contents are same.

Comment: Psst! Git commits are [snapshots, not diffs](https://github.blog/2020-12-17-commits-are-snapshots-not-diffs/). So C1 doesn't have "the same changes as C", but T..C1 has the same changes as B..C. I don't think it fundamentally changes anything about your question, but I think it should be pointed out.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I can rephrase that word... but essentially you got the idea what I am looking for... i.e. are those changes are same or not?

Comment: I'd simply pipe both diff outputs to files and do a simple `diff diff1.txt diff2.txt`, but there might be a simpler/better way.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Should T..C1 not have the same changes as A..B..C (instead of just B..C)? Because, as you said, you merge a snapshot not just the changes of one commit.

Answer (score 0):

See [Joachim Sauer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405157/git-show-the-difference-between-two-git-diff#comment119142085_67405157) for what is probably the simplest and most useful method of doing this.  Note, however, that since Git 2.19, Git has contained a new command, `git range-diff`, that is aimed at something a bit different, but can do exactly this sort of thing.

Because its *goal* is different, the easiest way to invoke `git range-diff`—using the three-dot notation—won't do what you want, but `git range-diff C~..C C1~..C1` is pretty straightforward.  See [the `git range-diff` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff) for more details.

(For automation purposes, consider using `git patch-id`.  A simple `git show hash | git patch-id` suffices to get a patch ID.)